# Calculating turnaround and total wait time for FCFS and SFJ

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, job-scheduling

I was given an assignment in which I have to calculate both the turnaround and total wait time based on:

Process Name:                              P1  |  P2  |  P3  |

Time of Arrival:                           P1=0      P2=2      P3=8

Total execution time:                      P1=10     P25      P3=27

Time needed for IO operations:             P1=1.5    P2=2      P3=1.1

IO operations waiting and processing time: P1=5      P2=5      P3=3.5

Priority:                                  P1=2      P2=1      P3=4

I found some info online saying that the turnaround time can be calculated by **turnaround = total execution time - time of arrival** and the total wait time can be calculated using **total wait time = turnaround time - total execution time** when you're only given the arrival time and the total execution time (CPU burst I think?).

How would the formulas above look like in this case since I have some extra info like the time needed for IO operations and IO operations waiting and processing time?

Comment: time needed for IO op & IO op waiting and processing time ? what's the difference ?!

Comment: I took a look at it and during both the IO op & IO op waiting and processing time, the process is out of the CPU.